# Eclipse showing code changes like in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I'm transitioning from Netbeans to Eclipse.

On Eclipse, I tried to install Subclipse, and yes I could see those markers if I modify the code. But when I press save, all those marks disappears.

Not on Netbeans, where those marks still remains, only if I commit the changes in the SVN.

How to persist those marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Text Editors --> Quick diff.

Check the checkbox labelled "Show differences in overview ruler".

Also change "Use this reference source" to "Pristine SVN Copy" & click on Apply/OK.

You can also change the colors of the markers.